# When does Ubuntu 12.04 run network if-pre-up.d and if-up.d scripts?

Tags: networking, server

I want to reload my previous firewall rules using an iptables-restore when my Ubuntu 12.04 server boots up. I'm using a VPS, and the virtualization backend writes to `/etc/init.d/networking`, so I'm not able to use `pre-up` command there (because it will just be overwritten).  After reading the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Solution_.232_.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-network.2BAC8-if-pre-up.d_and_...2BAC8-if-post-down.d), I tried to use both `if-preup.d` and `if-up.d` to run my firewall script. However, after restarting my server the script I placed in either of these directories was not run.

This is a no-gui, base Ubuntu 12.04 server VM that does not have network-manager installed.

Comment: What are the contents of the file '/etc/network/interfaces'?

Comment: It's an `inet static` configuration that is maintained by the virtualization backend we use.  Like I said, it gets overwritten, so I can't use it for any custom configuration with `pre-up`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use an `iptable` frontend instead of writing `iptables`-commands directly. I usually use `ufw` or `shorewall`. I use `ufw` on servers and `shorewall` on machines that forward networks, as iptables itself is unnecessarily complicated for a simple one-interface firewall.
Both of the aforementioned front-ends usually take care of all needed settings. `ufw` also sets up the firewall for IPv6.

`if-pre-up.d` and `if-up.d` are only run for interfaces that are managed by `ifupdown`. That is, they must be mentioned in `/etc/network/interfaces`. As mentioned in the manpage of `interfaces`, they are executed before and during setup of the interface that is being brought up.

Comment: Oh, and always check your firewall from outside with `nmap`.  That is a great tool for this.